# Implement interface that is not part of the public Android API

Tags: java, android

I want to implement an interface SelChImpl which is part of Android's [libcore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/ojluni/src/main/java/sun/nio/ch/SelChImpl.java). This class is not part of the Android API. But it is there at runtime and can be accessed using

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl");
```

for example. I have downloaded the libcore source code and now I want to add it to the "include path" (as you would call it in C). I don't want to compile the SelChImpl source code into my program. I just want to reference the class. How to do that? My code is:

```
package mypackage;

import sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl;
import java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel;

public class UnixSocketChannelImpl
  extends AbstractSelectableChannel
  implements SelChImpl
{
```

Later I am adding an instace of my class to a Selector:

```
Selector sel = Selector.open();
UnixSocketChannelImpl sock = new UnixSocketChannelImpl(/* some arguments here */);
sock.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

But I get this error:

> error: package sun.nio.ch does not exist

I think I need some gadle compileOnly directive?

Comment: i don't have much experience with this, but it doesn't seem too safe to rely on on something which isn't officially supported, it might be removed in future

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are dealing with `SocketChannelImpl` or `SelChImpl` ?

Comment: What kind of insane mind names interfaces using `Impl` suffix?

Comment: Add jar with that lib to your project classpath

Comment: I want to implement SelChImpl. I will check if this interface exists in the Android versions I am targeting. So it's quite save to do that.

Comment: @Antoniossss That would mean I have to compile libcore? I don't know how to do that...

Comment: It would be better got get compiled jar.

Comment: A workaround to this, instead of implementing interface, you could create a `Proxy` to intercept method calls and execute arbitrary code as you see fit in response. In such case, you dont even need sources because everything then is reflection based.

Comment: @Antoniossss I want to add an object of my class to a Selector. Something like this cannot be done using reflection or a proxy class. (See my edit in the post.)

Comment: Sure you can use proxy for that. After all, implementing interface is just saying what to do when client calls method X - exactly the same thing is done via proxy, just in more cumbersome way. IMO it can be done via proxy, the only question is will you be able to do it in cleaner way. If you run out of ideas you could take a shot with javas Proxy .

Comment: You just implement your class as you do now, but without `implements X`. Then you define proxy as a handler to handle method X eg via yourImplnstance.Y(params);

Comment: My object hast to be of type SelChImpl. If this is not the case I cannot add it to the selector. This can't be done using a proxy class. If you still think so then please post some code.

Comment: You would pass proxy, not impl, because proxy `implements X` :)

Comment: The class sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl checks if the object is of type SelChImpl. If I remove the "implements SelChImpl" then the code won't work.

Comment: you would pass proxy, not your impl and proxy would be of `SelChImpl` type obviously

Comment: @Antoniossss This would cause a IllegalSelectorException.

Comment: @Antoniossss Can you please post some code?  I don't understand...

Comment: On what basis IllegalSelectorException would be thrown? Did you tried it? Are you familiar with Mockito in tests for example? It would work in very similar way like passing a mock there. Check some examples of how java proxies can be used so you can try it out yourself. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html 

again, its not a clean solution, but should relief your from having sources/bytecode of corelib

Comment: @Antoniossss Because it stands in the code. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/519adb2f61bb2bfa6cc993b1ca15cf7022b96697/ojluni/src/main/java/sun/nio/ch/SelectorImpl.java#127

Comment: But the proxy WILL BE OF `SelChImpl`  and will pass `instanceof` check? That is the whole point! (assuming that `SelChImpl` is really an interface)

Comment: The fact that `register` accepts `AbstractSelectableChannel` is a different pair of shooes ....

Comment: @Antoniossss I'm sorry. I did not know about reflection Proxy classes. I checked it and it might work...

Comment: What do you want to achieve? / Why do you want to implement that class?

Comment: I want to have a selectable local unix socket